# Prevent accidental update of host database WebMatrix

Tags: webmatrix, msdeploy, web-deployment-project

I use WebMatrix for deployment of files and databases during development.  I want to continue to use it after development for updating files on the host.  I also want to synchronize my local database to the host database, but never the other way around.  I am terrified of accidentally overwriting  the database on the host.

How can I do what I want while safeguarding against accidental updates of the database on the host?  Essentially, I am looking for a way to tell WebMatrix that the host database is read only and not to be updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can link the development project to the live database.  That way you can still develop the files offline while using the actual data to do it.  If you link to the database WebMatrix won't attempt to update it as it will already be working with it.  Yes, if you make a change for development purposes it will change it on the live site.  However, if you are only developing the webpages this should not be a concern.  To link to your database just go to the database workspace and click on the New Connection icon.  Just remember any changes to the database in WebMatrix after that point will be immediately sent to your database.

Comment: I marked it as an answer, but for security reasons I don't allow remote clients to connect to my live db.